# How to approach proofs in Electricity and Magnitism that involve integrals?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, integration

I have read through both Franklin and Jackson's Electromagnetism books and I am able to understand the different proofs involving integrals but when I try to re-derive them on my own later I am always at a loss.

I understand the different versions of the fundamental theorem of calculous like Gauss's law and Stokes's theorem, I understand the divergence trick, I understand the vector identities like BAC-CAB or $\nabla\cdot r=3$  but I don't seem to have an intuition of these ideas or a general idea of how to manipulate integral formulas or be able to expect where a proof will lead.

I have tried writing down the above relations and I have tried learning about differential forms but the first approach didn't seem to help and I couldn't find a good introduction on differential forms.  Does any one have any ideas on how to conceptualize these proofs so that the approach is intuitively apparent? Thanks

Edit* I think my main difficulty is seeing what integral manipulations will lead to a simpler equation.  Each step in many of the proofs seem like aimless manipulations until the end.

Comment: Jackson will have two lines where the amount of work between the two lines really does take pages if you work out all the details. It doesn't mean you are doing it wrong if your work takes many steps it just means that not everything is easy. Don't think it is easy just because Jackson didn't show the steps, it just means he didn't want to show the steps.

Comment: @Timaeus Thanks.  That might be the case, that I'm imagining I can work things out on my own quickly and give up to quickly but other times I think I have more trouble seeing motivation for why to go in that direction.  Like when trying to find a simple expression for the vector potential of a magnetic dipole, each step doesn't seem like a necessity. Rather it seems like aimless manipulations just about till the end.

Comment: Hey Shane I found this short course on forms and thought of you; you might like to [check this out](http://brickisland.net/cs177/?cat=5)

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance Awesome! that is very helpful.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any universal "intuition" to tap into, aside from that which comes from practice. You perhaps need to explore different physics texts in the electromagnetic department. I for example loathed Jackson as a learning text: it is comprehensive and useful as a reference for refreshing knowledge, but not good at conveying it. [Volume 2 of the Feynman Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_toc.html) is a text I found excellent for a first course in electromagnetism.

There are two approaches I would take.

**Geometrical Definitions of Nabla Operations**

You mention that you are comfortable with Gauss's divergence theorem and Stokes's theorem. I would go back to the visual demonstrations of them as given in a good textbook - I recall "Vector Analysis" by Murray R. Spiegel having some wonderful diagrams along these lines - thinking of them  as statements flux through surfaces and the relationship between this flux and the divergence within a closed bounding surface /  line integral of the line bounding a surface and what happens when you shrink the surface / volume to infinitessimal size. This does two things: it gets you near to the original, integral forms of the equations of electromagnetism but more importantly it gives you a co-ordinate free way to *define* the divergence and curl of a vector field: *define* the component of the curl in a given direction as the limit of the line integral of a vector field around a loop in a plane normal to that direction divided by the loop's area: Stokes's theorem then becomes merely a proof that this procedure is well defined: the rest, *i.e.* the quantitative part about the flux of the curl through a loop being equal to the line integral around the loop then follows *by definition*. Likewise for the divergence (think of it as the nett flux out of a volume divided by the volume). Once you grasp the divergence and curl as definitions of geometric objects and not as collections of components, this might help. As an aside, you can see that the curl is defined in general in terms of a *planar* element of a surface, not the unit normal. The unit normal works in three dimensions - there is at most one plane through a point with a given unit normal in three dimensions - but you must think of the plane in higher dimensions as there is more than one plane through a point with a given unit normal so the unit normal is no longer useful in defining a plane.

**Differential Forms**

I think your approach of learning about forms is a good one and, notwithstanding frustrations, one you must persevere with. New paradigms like this are often good to pick up, mull over, then leave aside for a while before coming back to after you have processed them for a few days. Once you have thought about the nabla operator as I describe above, forms are a fairly natural step. Here you learn that the Stokes and Gauss theorems are two aspects of the same thing: the fundamental theorem of exterior calculus, which is simply a generalized form of Newton's fundamental calculus theorem. Two good texts here are:

[Bernard Schutz, "Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521298873) Chapter 4 "Differential Forms"

and

[Roger Penrose, "The Road to Reality"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679776311) Chapter 12 "Manifolds of in n-Dimensions" and Chapter 14 "Calculus on Manifolds"

[Lovelock and Rund, "Tensors, Differential Forms and Variational Principles"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486658406)

This might sound crazy, but once you have battled with electromagnetism for a while, something like Chapter 4 "Electromagnetism and Differential Forms" of Misner Thorne and Wheeler, "Gravitation" or Penrose's discussion in Chapter 19 "The Classical Fields on Maxwell and Einstein" of "Road to Reality" are wondeful summaries to mull over. But you must learn a lower level approach first, because both these discussions move fast and do not prove much of what they say, but what they do say ties everything together beautifully.